# React JS - Web App (Not React Native) - Open custom app not working -- using Custom App web URL

Tags: reactjs

React JS - Web App (Not React Native) - Open custom app not working using Custom App web URL

Try to run below code but not working

On page load event just try to dynamically click anchor tag not working
but if I do manually it is working

previously I have this kind of URL and it's working

**swsdl://example**

but now I have this URL
**https://example.com (this is app web URL)**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect , useRef} from "react";
import OpenApp from "react-open-app";
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const OpenApplication2 = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams(window.location.href);
  const addButtonRef1 = useRef();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  const OpenApp1 = () => {
    debugger;
    addButtonRef1.current.click();
  }

  useEffect(() => {    
    var fileName = searchParams.get("FileName");      
    setMessage(fileName);  

    
    console.log("1:" + fileName);

    if(message != "")  
    {     
      document.getElementById("app1").click();
      
      console.log("2:" + fileName);   
    }
    
  }, [message]);

  return (
    <div className="App">            
      <br></br>  

   
      <a id='app1' href='https://example.com?xyz.glb'>Lunch App</a>             
    </div>
  );
};

export default OpenApplication2;
```